# Hosting and update version concurrency for asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, version-control, hosting, versioning, web-hosting

My question is simple and straightforward: I am new to hosting and its process. I have Web Application and I have to host it. I dont know where to host and how? In my list there are Godaddy.com and hostcat.com for hosting and I want to use filezilla for updating the Application. But My concern is my application have Payment gateway and I do not want my site to get down for a minute while updating the version. 
Now my question is **How to maintain concurrency while updating the application? Any solution where should I host the application and what software should I use for updating**.

Any solution or tutorial are highly appreciated.